# Cannot set property 'innerHTML', 'style' of null problem

Tags: javascript, html, console, innerhtml

I have a problem when I use any property `innerHTML` or `style`

when I use that console give me an error

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**

### My Code

#### HTML

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
  // Time Element
  var time = document.querySelector("#time");

  // Output
  let digital = `${digitalHours}:${digitalMin}`;

  // innerHTML problem
  time.innerHTML = digital;
```

> `<script>` tag are located in end of `<body>` tag

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: The error is clear. `ele` doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you share some more code? It looks like your variable `ele` does not exist. this can be due to multiple reasons.

Comment: I post my code.

Comment: `ele` still doesn't exist. Please post the html it refers to and the javascript that retrieves and references it.

Comment: ele is already exist. but i don't put it in the code because the problem doesn't from ele. I put it now!

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` is referring to the element that you are attempting to access the `innerHTML` or `style` of, which, in your example, seems to be `ele`. What makes you think it's not `ele`?

Comment: So, the element that `time` references doesn't exist? You really need to produce a [mcve] for us to be able to help, and you should do some debugging of your code through the console.

Comment: ok, I edit my question to be more clearly.